# I want to process PCA in a time series data.sample data format is attached here. total data size is in 40 columns and 40 rows

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzghZ.jpg)

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as sklearnPCA
sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components=2)
Y_sklearn = sklearn_pca.fit_transform(X_std)
data = []

for name, col in zip(('Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica'), colors.values()):

    trace = dict(
        type='scatter',
        x=Y_sklearn[y==name,0],
        y=Y_sklearn[y==name,1],
        mode='markers',
        name=name,
        marker=dict(
            color=col,
            size=12,
            line=dict(
                color='rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.14)',
                width=0.5),
            opacity=0.8)
    )
    data.append(trace)

layout = dict(
        xaxis=dict(title='PC1', showline=False),
        yaxis=dict(title='PC2', showline=False)
)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='pca-scikitlearn')
```

please guide me through this ways as i have been following other longer ways in python to do PCA

Comment: What is working properly? What is not working properly? Simply asking us to _guide you_ does not tell us what your ***programming problem*** is.

Comment: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Z65ndvXwRF0J:https://plot.ly/scikit-learn/plot-pca-3d/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ch

Comment: how to input the info in the file i have shared...its a variable across different stations..simply how to make it readable for further analysis in this code first